# How do I buy Team Fortress 2 items outside of the game?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

In the last year, Valve implemented a way to buy in-game items in Steam. On [this page](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Mann_Co._Supply_Crate_Key) you can see a link to buy keys on the right side, which links to [here](http://store.steampowered.com/buyitem/440/5079)

But going to that link gives an error:

> One or more of the items requested are not for sale.

How do you buy TF2 items (keys) on Steam and not in TF2?

Comment: Why would you want to buy it outside of TF2?  Buying it in the Mann Co store in-game removes funds from steam wallet just the same.

Comment: There could be a sale on, and he might be unable to start up TF2 (i.e. at mates house who dont have steam + TF2 installed, computer being fixed and so using a old pc that cant run TF2 are two that I can think of)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this may not be the only way, this is a way that works:

Go to this [site](http://www.teamfortress.com/), and scoll down until you see the "Contact us" box on the right hand side of the webpage. Right above it will be another, smaller box with "Supply Crate Keys" on it. Click the link, and you should be able to buy a key (Tested myself)

As to why the wiki site link didn't work, I would guess that the sites link is broken, possibly linking to a old store page

Comment: There's now a button that links to the Steam Community Market, but requires manually filtering to only see TF2 items. [This link](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_440_Type%5B%5D=any&appid=440) goes directly to the TF2 items view there.

Answer (score 5):

[Mann Co. Online Store](http://store.teamfortress.com/)

Once you make your first purchase, you get the [Mann Co Online Cap](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Mann_Co._Online_Cap) (different from the Mann Co. Cap).

[image]

Since your post also references keys, you can also try Steam Marketplace.  Think of it as a community market for the sale of certain TF2 items, and it's accessible from the main Steam panel.

http://steamcommunity.com/market/

Answer (score 0):

You want to buy TF2 keys outside the game client, throught the web browser ?

The online store, at TF2 website, is currently closed: ***store.teamfortress.com*** .

Currently, there are no way to browse or find TF2 keys in Steam Store: ***store.steampowered.com*** .

**But**, you can buy using specific links to the items, which will add the items to your cart on Steam Store.

The link to buy a key is: http://store.steampowered.com/buyitem/440/5021 .
(Note the item id "5021" at the end, not "5079" as you provided.)
(This is a official and safe way to buy, as stated here: ***www.teamfortress.com/buynow_faq/***)

One way to **browse** for items, is to look for them in the official TF2 Wiki (ans you did): https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Mann_Co._Supply_Crate_Key

So, probably the Wiki was outdated at the time you visited it (or the item id changed).

And, of course, you can buy it from other players at the (also official) Steam Community Market: ***steamcommunity.com/market/***

Answer (score -4):

marketplace.tf there you go.  :-)

Comment: Hi Onionheadtex, weclome to the site. While marketplace.tf is a viable solution, this answer would be a lot more useful if you could explain how to use marketplace.tf, where to buy keys, can the user use cash or must they use ref or in-game item trades, etc etc.